# for loop in remotely executed bash script does not work

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, ssh

I have a remote bash script, which goes through files using a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.pdf;
do
        echo $f
done
```

When executed locally:

```
server$./test.sh
1508.01585.pdf
1605.07683.pdf
```

When executed through ssh from a remote client:

```
client$ ssh user@server 'bash -c ~/papers/test.sh'
*.pdf
```

I have tried using `ssh -T`, `bash -s`, and nothing seems to work.

Please help!

Comment: This means that there are no matching files in the remote user's home directory

Comment: Maybe your current directory isn't what you think it is, and there are no `*.pdf` files?  Use a full name like`/home/user/papers/*.pdf`or whatever.

Comment: That is it! I was just not expecting that the '*.pdf' return was because there were not files found, but rather that it was not looping. Thank you! Please post as answer to accept it.

Comment: Or put a `cd` command at the beginning of the script, to change to the directory that contains the files.

Comment: @cduguet See the `nullglob` bash option. By default a glob returns itself if it doesn't match, if you set this option it returns an empty result.

Comment: @cduguet, I'd argue that this falls into the "problem that can no longer be reproduced or simple typographical error" category. If, by contrast, you were asking why `*.pdf` resolved to itself when no matches exist, then we could close-as-duplicate (it's already in the knowledgebase).